# Use a variable like this: set.color(Color.variable)

Tags: java, string, variables, colors

In this method I make a string variable, and move it to a different one.

```
    private void produceRainbow() {
       String color = "RED";
       produceArc(color);
    }
```

There is more code there but it does not matter (essentially, changing the string to other colors).

Next this method:

```
private void produceArc(String color) {
    GOval arc = new GOval(leftX, upperY, rightX, lowerY); 
    arc.setColor(Color.color);
}
```

(Ignore the variables leftX, upperY, rightX, lowerY)

Here I want to set the color to a string.
So I want it to become `arc.setColor(Color.RED)`

When I compile, I get this error:

```
Program.java:89: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable color
location: class java.awt.Color
    arc.setColor(Color.color);
```

Is it even possible to do what I want to do? If so, what am I doing wrong?

(If you're curious, I made a seperate method for each arc (red, blue, green, etc, all have their own method) and this works, but I was wondering if I could just use one method that takes a variable, which makes the code a lot shorter)

Comment: Do you really want to pass a string? You could just pass Color.RED right away.
Or if you really want to use a String, you could use Color.FromName(string name);

Comment: If you really want to use a String you could use reflection to get the static field with the name that matches the String, or build a map mapping the string to the Color instance. But those are ugly and unsafe (as far as type / compilation checks). I'd go with @James's suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate the comment I gave.

You could either pass the Color.RED right away or use Color.FromName(string name);

**Suggested method:**

To pass the Color.RED your methods will look like this:

```
private void produceRainbow() {
       Color color = Color.RED;
       produceArc(color);
    }
```

And:

```
private void produceArc(Color color) {
    GOval arc = new GOval(leftX, upperY, rightX, lowerY); 
    arc.setColor(color);
}
```

**Method 2**

If, for some reason, you would use the FromName method you'd apply it like below:

```
private void produceRainbow() {
       String color = "Red";
       produceArc(color);
    }
```

And:

```
private void produceArc(String color) {
    GOval arc = new GOval(leftX, upperY, rightX, lowerY); 
    arc.setColor(Color.FromName(color));
}
```

Note that this last method is only working in C# and is not suitable for Java. (I'm not sure whether you're using Java or C#)